# Using multiple files vs multiple buffers. What to use?

Tags: c, file-io, operating-system, disk-io

I have a program which creates two lists of numbers, sorted and stored on disk. The task is is to merge both the lists using linear merge. They both are sorted and fast to merge. One list contains 1,00,000 items and the other around 80,000. Each item is a 4 byte integer. Here is the layout:

list1 length | list1 | list2 length | list2

To merge there are two techniques:-

1. Use a buffer of say 1024*16 bytes and read from each of the list. First seek to the list1 then fetch and then same on the list2. And some integers may be ignored as it may not be present in the current buffer, so keep last unmatched integers to be matched while fetching the next buffer. Repeat until end of lists. This may require seeking many times.
2. Create two file pointer and read from each lists. Seek the first file pointer to the starting of list1 and the second file pointer to the start of list2.

My question is that reading buffer by buffer is good(You have to seek many times to each list) or using multiple file pointers? Is opening a single file multiple times good practice?
I think from the hardware level, both are the same but is there any difference from the software level or from the operating system side? The two lists are for example; I have multiple lists to merge.

Comment: Do it the simple way first (with file pointers). Time it, if you are happy, move on. If you are not, only then look to optmise. I doubt using your own buffer will help, because both C++ and your O/S will already be buffering the input, but you can try. Opening the same file multiple times is defintely bad. My intuition is that you will see the most difference depending on the API you use, C++ vs C vs Posix. But as always the only advice is to try different ways and time the results.

Comment: @IrAm I am using C now removed C++

Comment: @john Yeah I was thinking this, file pointer have their own buffer as well as I can use my buffer and using multiple file pointer is a bad practice. I will test it and compare the time. Thanks.

Comment: Since nowadays 100000 records are considered as "tiny" in PC environments, it would maybe be the best to read all data to RAM, do the operation there, and store the result

Comment: The "layout" is not self-explanatory.  Can you show what you mean?  Is it the input or the output format? Are you saying that the files contain 4-byte binary integers, written with `fread()`?  Are you aiming to omit duplicate entries — do you omit them from list1 or list2 (or both)?

Comment: Not "read" data but to **memory map** the data.

Comment: @Mr.Explorerexplorer the truth is there is the simple way: use two streams. There is the ultimate easy way: memory map all of the data. Everything in between is more complicated.

Comment: Have you measured the performance degradation?  ["Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I mean I store list1's length first then the list1 itself and then list2 length and list2 itself

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am going to test it now.

Comment: is it like `list1 5|1 2 3 4 5  list2 3| 1 2 3` in your file?

Comment: I tested it and found buffering is nice than multiple streams. But we have to take buffer of higher size of 32K. File took around 1.654s and buffer took 0.379 s. For buffer of 8K it took around 0.769 seconds.

Comment: @IrAM yes same way. It is a binary file

Comment: The memory required for storing 180,000 ints are not a problem on typical systems so just get the whole input file into memory and handle it. Or do you have some memory limitations that you didn't mention in the Q?

Comment: @Mr.Explorerexplorer: Stating execution times is useless for other people without reporting system and device characteristics in great detail, including model, version, and or characteristics of processor, bus, memory, disk controller, disk, compiler, operating system, and more.

Comment: In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65769610/using-multiple-files-vs-multiple-buffers-what-to-use?noredirect=1#comment116284375_65769610) (written late in the evening), I wrote "written by `fread()`' where I should (obviously, I hope) have said "written by `fwrite()` and read by `fread()`".